# QueryTable.Refresh on Password Protected Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I can unlock a sheet will, refresh my query, and then password protect my sheet.

However, it seems to double back to that protected sheet and try to edit it again, and throws an error saying the sheet is protected.

```vb
Sub QueryRefresh()

pwd = "example"
Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect pwd
Worksheets("Sheet2").Unprotect pwd
Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Query1").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Query2").QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=True
Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect pwd
Worksheets("Sheet2").Protect pwd
MsgBox "Success"

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try `application.wait` before you lock?

Comment: @findwindow that did not work. It seems to throw the error after the `MsgBox` which doesn't make much sense to me given the workflow.

Comment: When protecting them again, try using the UserInterfaceOnly parameter: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.protect

Comment: I thought this would work too, but still running into issues.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: If that is switched to False, the query will not refresh.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use: `Application.CalculateUntilAsyncQueriesDone`
It has worked for me.